# How to send request with chrome.extension regardless of user's cookie?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension, I want to make an independent request from user cookies in my requests from the extension background script.

In summary, if the user has access to the profile on the xxx.com site, I want to make a request as a different profile by sending my own cookies instead of the user cookies in the requests from the extension.

just as if you were making a request from the secret tab.

Comment: `fetch('https://example.com', {credentials: 'omit'})`

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, but I want to send me special cookies.

Comment: See documentation and examples for using chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders. Note, to add a Set-Cookie header you'l need 'extraHeaders' option as per the documentation.

Comment: See documentation and examples for using chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders. Note, to add a Set-Cookie header you'l need 'extraHeaders' option as per the documentation.